# How to make a program installation package with VS2019?

Tags: installation, mfc, package, visual-studio-2019

I learned how to make an installation package through this tutorial, but I encountered a problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/walkthrough-deploying-your-program-cpp?view=vs-2019#install-the-visual-studio-setup-and-deployment-project-template

I made the installation package strictly according to the tutorial. After clicking Primary Output, all the DLL files I needed appeared in the list on the right, but after I Build Solution, the names of the DLL files in the list were all cleared, and I got the installation package There is no DLL file either.

---

I found that when I added Project Output, the DLLs all appeared in the DetectedDependencies directory. Is there any problem?At this time I choose to generate the project, these DLL libraries will disappear, and the installation package does not contain any of them
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjXHY.png)

Comment: Please try to select `Locally-Copied Items` by right-click on the project-->`Add`-->`Project Output`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. I added the files manually and added the DLLs I needed one by one to complete the packaging. When I click the Primary Output button, the DLL list automatically generated by the system seems to be invalid. Just ignore it. This may be a BUG